# Saving/checking path based on cell value

Tags: vba, save, file-structure

I am trying to figure out how to check a path and save based on cell value. I was hoping to get an idea of what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

```
Sub Macro1()
        Sub CreateDir(strPath As String)
        Dim elm As Variant
        Dim strCheckPath As String

    strCheckPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\Edit Listings" & Worksheets("Private").Range("A10").Value & Worksheets("Private").Range("B10").Value & Worksheets("Private").Range("C10").Value
    For Each elm In Split(strPath, "\")
        strCheckPath = strCheckPath & elm & "\"
        If Len(Dir(strCheckPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir strCheckPath
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't have a `Sub` declaration within another `Sub`: `Sub Macro1()...
        Sub CreateDir(strPath As String)` isn't valid.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. Thanks!